# Android app with realTime database without using FIREBASE maybe Something like hooking on server

Tags: android, sql, android-volley

I have been coding an

> **android based Social Community application with RealTime database solution**

which is done by using Volley library to receive and send data from a PHP based server. The issue is I've been facing is my app needs to update **recyclerViews on RealTime**.

I have dealt with firebase before its quite a nice solution. But for this application I am not allowed to use Firebase. So is there any **solution for realTime database sync maintenance using SQL based backend**.

Comment: You can use Parse database..

Comment: please provide a snippet or link for the sample. thnx

Comment: @SardarKhan parse is dead  I heard

Comment: Ok thanks but you can use other databases as well.like realm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link for parse SDK
https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android
Here is the guide for how to use Parse in android
http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/
Here is the Tutorial for Integrating Parse in Android
http://pulse7.net/android/integrating-parse-sdk-cloud-based-services-android-application/

You can use Realm Database with android.Here is the tutorial for how to use Realm In android.
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/
https://dzone.com/articles/realm-practical-use-in-android

Comment: @SardarKhan Parse is dead from 28.01.2016, and servers officially after a year

Comment: its an old answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Realm](https://realm.io/). It's a `NoSql` local and cloud database, fast and powerful.